# drupal multiple interest of user

Tags: drupal

hi i want to **refresh user page** with different data but with same template (user-profile.tpl.php) by simply clicking tabs. Can any one suggest the best way to do that ?.

for ex:

```
tab1:sports , tab2: music tab3: literature
```

by clicking tabs the template is same but the data is going to refreshed.

**Note:** Look like profile categories but not the same. all details are from user table

Comment: When you say you want to refresh the data, do you me mean you want to change the data that is used to generate the output?

Comment: yes. simply changing the array data passed to user-profile.tpl.php for each tab click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way, which isn't exactly what you asked for, would be to using jQuery tabs or something similar to create the tabs effect. In other words get all the data but use CSS and JavaScript to handle which data should be displayed.

I don't think there is an easy way to split up the content of the user profile into tabs with pure html and Drupal.